# Scheduler start time not available in AynchApexJob

Tags: apex

From the AsyncApexjob object, I am unable to get the scheduled start time of a job.
Is there a way to get the start time of a apex job.

Answer (score 0):

Do a timestamp log in start line of execute Method.
OR retrieve it using SOQL query to AsyncApexJob.